# I am making a unity game and my ball keeps drifting to the side after it hit an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am working on a game where the ball should just hit an object and that's it but when it hits it keeps drifting to the side. The code's below are my Collision Script and my Movement script.

Collision Script:

```
        
`using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Movememt Movement;

   
    IEnumerator OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.name == "Obstacle")
        {
            Movement.enabled = false;
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(2);
            Movement.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}`
```

Movement Script:

```
        
`using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movememt : MonoBehaviour
{    // public float makes a variable
    // the f after .1 tells unity it is a variable
    public float speed = .1f;

    
    // Void Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {    // input.GetAxis("Horizontal")/("Vertical") tells the script how to move(wasd)
        float xDirection = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float zDirection = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 moveDirection = new Vector3(xDirection, 0.0f, zDirection);
        // this script tells it to actually move the object at the speed set in the top command
        transform.position += moveDirection * speed;
    }
    IEnumerator Pause()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
            Debug.Log("Wait is over");
    }
}`
```

Comment: Using a class name as a variable name is bad practice. You should change `public Movememt Movement;` to `public Movememt movement;` or another name

Comment: Also, you should probably multiply `moveDirection`  by `Time.deltaTime` to account for frame rate differences

Comment: [Also OnCollisionEnter is not a IIEnumerator](https://answers.unity.com/questions/181662/oncollisionenter-as-ienumerator-problem-waitforsec.html)

Comment: @BCT a) that is an opinion and there is nothing wrong with `public Movement Movement;` I would not say it is bad practice if your naming convention is uppercase for public fields. b) [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) **can** be `IEnumerator` (See bottom of that page though bad formulated) in which case Unity automatically runs it as a Coroutine! This is true for not all but many event messages like e.g. also `Start` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that on your balls rigidbody component Linear and angular Drag are set to 0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).